# How to change the AR Foundation Camera Rotation and position using joystick in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcamera

I am creating a project like AR Portal in the AR foundation.
there are two modes in this:

1. AR Mode
2. Joystick Mode

Everything is going well with AR Camera and in AR mode.
In joystick mode, I am unable to rotate the camera and I am stuck on that problem and didn't find any solution.
If I disabled the Tracked pose Driver of AR Camera, then it will work but if I enable the Tracked Pose Driver, then it will not work.

Is it possible to rotate the camera when Tracked Pose Driver is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. AR camera is usually a physical camera, changing its position and rotation by code would not make a lot of sense. If you are using the joystick for a different scene/ part of the scene, try using a regular Unity camera and write a simple controller to move it around.